# How to get all non distinct data from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

## Problem Statement:

I need to retrieve all non-distinct data from the below collection that is based on Tin fieldName using Mongo aggregation.

I can retrieve the count using the query below, but I also need all the data.

```js
db.Demo.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Tin",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Vin": "$_id",
      "_id": 0,
      "count": "$count"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

## Mongo Sample Collection:

```json
[
  {
    Tin: "5051",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "ECE",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    Tin: "5051",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "ECE",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    Tin: "5055",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "ECE",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    Tin: "5055",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "ECE",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    Tin: "5052",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "CHN",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    Tin: "5053",
    Status: "DOCUMENTED",
    Region: "AMAP",
    ActionDateTime: ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24.000+00:00"),
    FM: "XYZ"
  }
]
```

## Expected out: Get all duplicate data based on Tin

```json
[
  {
    "ActionDateTime": ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24Z"),
    "FM": "XYZ",
    "Region": "ECE",
    "Status": "DOCUMENTED",
    "Tin": "5055"
  },
  {
    "ActionDateTime": ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24Z"),
    "FM": "XYZ",
    "Region": "ECE",
    "Status": "DOCUMENTED",
    "Tin": "5055"
  },
  {
    "ActionDateTime": ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24Z"),
    "FM": "XYZ",
    "Region": "ECE",
    "Status": "DOCUMENTED",
    "Tin": "5051"
  },
  {
    "ActionDateTime": ISODate("2022-08-21T00:46:24Z"),
    "FM": "XYZ",
    "Region": "ECE",
    "Status": "DOCUMENTED",
    "Tin": "5051"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple `$group`. Filter by the `$count` > 1. Then perform back `$lookup` and `$unwind` to get back the dupes. One caveat is that we don't simply push all document in an array at the `$group` stage since too many records may break the 16MB document limit. We work around that by perform `$lookup` and `$unwind` at later stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Tin",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "Tin",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AhNF_KipESi) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment. let me try this.

Comment: I ran above query but getting distict value. please help to find non distinct. I mean all the duplicate values based on Tin

Comment: Sorry for distorting your question by my misunderstanding. Update the answer to find the dupes.

Comment: Thank you. much appriciated.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted in order to avoiding duplicate effort from the community to check the issues again